# Convert object to XML string without annotaions on the POJO

Tags: xml, json, spring, rest

Is there a way to convert object to XML string without using annotaions on the POJO class? My request comming as a REST service and it automatically converts to the POJO object. I need to get the XML string from this object. But does not like to change the POJO classes as it is a another task.Please reply me

Comment: Xstream you can check.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need *that* many annotations on your objects for JAXB (mostly `@XmlRootElement`) **if** your objects are neat and clean.

If you want absolutely no annotations [EclipseLink MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) is one JAXB implementation which can use [XML files to define the mapping](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/moxy/runtime003.htm) instead.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache xml-beans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/), can solve your requirement. It uses an xml mapping file, and does not require any annotations.